# longest palindrome in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

**Write a method that takes in a string of lowercase letters (no uppercase letters, no repeats). Consider the *substrings* of the string: consecutive sequences of letters contained inside the string.
Find the longest such string of letters that is a palindrome.**

Based on local method Palindrome?(string), I implemented longest-palindrome(string) as below with test cases:

```
def palindrome?(string)
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    if string[i] != string[(string.length - 1) - i]
      return false
    end

    i += 1
  end

  return true
end

def longest_palindrome(string)
  dix = 0
  lstr = ""
  lstrc = nil
  while dix < string.length
    dix2 = 1
    while dix2 < string.length
      str = string.slice(dix,dix2)
      count = str.length
      if palindrome?(str)
        if lstrc == nil || lstrc < count
          lstr = str
          lstrc = count
        end
      end
      dix2 += 1
    end
    dix += 1
  end
  puts(lstr)
  return lstr
end

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.

puts(
  'longest_palindrome("abcbd") == "bcb": ' +
  (longest_palindrome('abcbd') == 'bcb').to_s
)
puts(
  'longest_palindrome("abba") == "abba": ' +
  (longest_palindrome('abba') == 'abba').to_s
)
puts(
  'longest_palindrome("abcbdeffe") == "effe": ' +
  (longest_palindrome('abcbdeffe') == 'effe').to_s
)
```

Test results as below:

```
bcb                                                                                                                                                                                    
longest_palindrome("abcbd") == "bcb": true                                                                                                                                             
bb                                                                                                                                                                                     
longest_palindrome("abba") == "abba": false                                                                                                                                            
effe                                                                                                                                                                                   
longest_palindrome("abcbdeffe") == "effe": true
```

Why did the second test failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... this line is preventing you from considering the entire string

```
while dix2 < string.length
```

So when `dix` is the whole string, you're not doing any testing for palindromes

Change the line to...

```
while dix2 <= string.length
```

It would actually be slightly more efficient if you did...

```
while dix2 <= string.length - dix
```

Which would prevent you from testing (for, say, a string of length 10), `string(7,3)` and `string(7,4)` and `string(7,5)` etc. etc., which are all basically the same string.

Comment: It worked!!  I am just a little confused because enabling dix2 equals string.length, wouldn't it reach out of the string boundary?

Comment: No, it would be exactly the string boundary because the second argument of `slice` is the number of characters you want.  So `"abba".slice(0,4)` returns "abba" but `"abba".slice(0,3)` only returns "abb"

Comment: This is very helpful! I mistakenly thought the second argument was the end position.

Comment: Incidentally, a way, way easier way to code your `palindrome?` method would be in one line... `return string == string.reverse` the "string == string.reverse" will return true or false and that value is then returned.  In fact, since the last executable line of a method is returned automatically, you don't even need to specify the "return"... just have one line `string == string.reverse`

Comment: And one more suggestion... the `dix = 0; while dix <= string.length; ...; dix += 1; end` that's a very "un-rubyish" way of doing it.  Much more common and compact is `(0..string.length).each do |dix|`  and then just `end` at the end.  that will automatically assign every value from 0 to string.length to `dix` for you.  `(0..string.length)` with two dots does all values from 0 to string.length and `(0...string.length)` with three dots does 0 to string.length minus 1, so it automatically excludes the end value.